# TerminateThread to all my created threads, but the program still won't close?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++

I killed off all my threads and the dialog box disappears, but it still runs... I can see it as a Process still running.  So I have to then kill the process.

`exit(0)` is probably not the best way to close out of an app.  Is there another way, or is this the best?  thx

---

The following code helped the debugger, otherwise it crashed OnClose.

```
void CServerDlg::OnClose() 
{
    TerminateThread(this->hThread_TcpIp, 0);
    TerminateThread(this->hThread_ReadData, 0);
    TerminateThread(this->hThread_ReadSetup, 0);

    //exit(0); //<-- not good to use
    CDialog::OnClose();
}
```

Comment: `TerminateThread()` is not exactly the best way to close out an application either. In fact, `TerminateThread()` is a "last resort" function if anything else.

Comment: This is a pretty bad way to terminate a program.  As long as you have to resort to killing threads instead of asking them nicely to exit then using exit(0) is a better way to terminate.  Elevated to a standard in C++11, review std::quick_exit()

Answer (score 0):

If CCatsServerDlg is the main dialog of the application, simply calling OnOK() or OnCancel() will terminate the application. There is no need to terminate each thread. They will be automatically terminated when the process exits.

You can also try *PostQuitMessage*.

Comment: OnOk, OnCancel, OnClose:  all of them would crash the debugger.  Not until I put TerminateThread did that stop happening.  But the release executable will show that as a process it is still running even though the  dialog closed.

Answer (score 0):

**The no nos:**

You should never use exit() to terminate Windows application.

You should not call message handler directly, since most of the messages (including WM_CLOSE) are issued by the system after performing some steps.

You should never use TerminateThread according to MSDN:

***TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases.***

You should never close an app without terminating all threads, since each thread must perform some cleaning. For example free memory and Windows handles. This is not a good programming practice, since terminating process may release memory but most likely all Windows resources (user and system) would not be released.

**What you should do:**

Use synchronization mechanism to terminate threads if you are using worker threads. For this I would suggest using an event object. You can use PostQuitMessage only for the threads that have a message queue, usually GUI threads.

After requesting threads termination you should use WaitForMultipleObjects function and after threads are terminated, terminate the main thread.

If your dialog is a modal main application window, call EndDialog. After dialog terminates, you should return FALSE from the application InitInstance.

If you dialog is not a modal dialog, after terminating threads, you should call DestroyWindow.

Comment: Why should you not use `exit()` to exit your program?  There's really nothing wrong with it.  A reusable function shouldn't use it, only the main program, but that's a different issue.